# combined probability for product surveys

Tags: probability

I need to setup basic math calculation for setting up combined probability to find out customer overall impression on some products. The question might be

1. How satisfied are you with product A(1 to 10)
   say answer is : 9
   p(satisfaction)=0.9
2. Do you wish to recommend it to other friend
   say answer is :2
   p(recommendation)=0.2

So I can apply some probability rule to analyse customer  perception towards this product.

Assuming satisfaction and recommendation are two independent event the combined result will be 
p(satisfaction and recommendation)= 0.18 which is fairly low as user is very satisfied to the product. What is the best way for this type of analysis?

Comment: Its very unlikely that those two measures are independent. Do you have access to the data (can you derive the correlation?)

Comment: Yes I have access to data .This is the survey http://www.surveygizmo.com/s3/4165346/Test-Product-Survey-dev?c=1234321&p=moccona+coffee&ca=test+campaign+1&pr=120080

Comment: In my experience there are usually more than two Q's and the 'index of satisfaction' may be a weighted sum of all. In some customer satisfaction surveys the only Q taken may come last: the customer's overall satisfaction score on a scale of 1-5 Expecting even unsatisfied customers to be reluctant to pick low scores, great emphasis is put on the 5's. (The early Q's are mainly just to guide subjects to think in directions the firm thinks relevant: such as speed, attentiveness, politeness of service.) More of a psych game than statistics Pre-testing of surveys is crucial to usefulness.

Comment: weighted sum sounds interesting